# Is it possible to delete a table from Azure Table Storage using AzCopy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azcopy

I'm building a set of Webjobs to back up my Azure Storage blobs and tables to a separate storage account (to be used in the case of unintentional corruption of data, in which case the built in replication wouldn't be useful).

I've successfully built jobs to both backup and restore the data. I'm now working on a job to delete old backups and I can delete blobs, but I'm having trouble with deleting tables. AzCopy 10 has the *remove* operation, but does not support tables. AzCopy 7.3 supports tables but does not appear to have a way to delete objects. Am I missing something here, or is my only option to somehow call the REST API to delete these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something here, or is my only option to somehow call the
>   REST API to delete these tables?

If I am not mistaken, that functionality is not there in AzCopy.

Regarding using REST API, I don't think you would need to do that. You can simply use Azure Storage .Net SDK (which is a wrapper over REST API) to do delete operations on objects.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I went with, and since I was already processing the connection string for azCopy, it was incredibly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it. Run `azcopy --help` for a complete list of commands or  Run `azcopy remove --help` for a complete list of actions availble to remove command

```
Usage:
  azcopy remove [resourceURL] [flags]

Aliases:
  remove, rm, r

Examples:

Remove a single blob by using a SAS token:

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]"

Remove an entire virtual directory by using a SAS token:

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]" --recursive=true

Remove only the blobs inside of a virtual directory, but don't remove any subdirectories or blobs within those subdirectories:

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/virtual/dir]" --recursive=false

Remove a subset of blobs in a virtual directory (For example: remove only jpg and pdf files, or if the blob name is "exactName"):

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]" --recursive=true --include="*.jpg;*.pdf;exactName"

Remove an entire virtual directory but exclude certain blobs from the scope (For example: every blob that starts with foo or ends with bar):

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]" --recursive=true --exclude="foo*;*bar"

Remove specific blobs and virtual directories by putting their relative paths (NOT URL-encoded) in a file:

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/parent/dir]" --recursive=true --list-of-files=/usr/bar/list.txt
   - file content:
           dir1/dir2
           blob1
           blob2

Remove a single file from a Blob Storage account that has a hierarchical namespace (include/exclude not supported):

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].dfs.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/file]?[SAS]"

Remove a single directory from a Blob Storage account that has a hierarchical namespace (include/exclude not supported):

   - azcopy rm "https://[account].dfs.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]"


Flags:
      --delete-snapshots string   By default, the delete operation fails if a blob has snapshots. Specify 'include' to remove the root blob and all its snapshots; alternatively specify 'only' to remove only the snapshots but keep the root blob.
      --exclude-path string       Exclude these paths when removing. This option does not support wildcard characters (*). Checks relative path prefix. For example: myFolder;myFolder/subDirName/file.pdf
      --exclude-pattern string    Exclude files where the name matches the pattern list. For example: *.jpg;*.pdf;exactName
  -h, --help                      help for remove
      --include-path string       Include only these paths when removing. This option does not support wildcard characters (*). Checks relative path prefix. For example: myFolder;myFolder/subDirName/file.pdf
      --include-pattern string    Include only files where the name matches the pattern list. For example: *.jpg;*.pdf;exactName
      --list-of-files string      Defines the location of a file which contains the list of files and directories to be deleted. The relative paths should be delimited by line breaks, and the paths should NOT be URL-encoded.
      --log-level string          Define the log verbosity for the log file. Available levels include: INFO(all requests/responses), WARNING(slow responses), ERROR(only failed requests), and NONE(no output logs). (default 'INFO') (default "INFO")
      --recursive                 Look into sub-directories recursively when syncing between directories.

Flags Applying to All Commands:
      --cap-mbps uint32      Caps the transfer rate, in megabits per second. Moment-by-moment throughput might vary slightly from the cap. If this option is set to zero, or it is omitted, the throughput isn't capped.
      --output-type string   Format of the command's output. The choices include: text, json. The default value is 'text'. (default "text")
```

Comment: I did have a look at the options for both versions, and as far as I can tell v10 definitely doesn't (and will never) support tables, and v7 is expressly intended just for copy.